# SQL Table not updating

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

At the minute I have three tables:

ebook details: ID, Ebook Name

Ebook Info: Name of Book, Purchased by, Date

Person Details: Person Name, Email

The ebook details table has been updated with information
The ebook info table is currently blank. 
The Person Details table is the one I am trying to update with a .csv file and it will not.

It is giving me this error, help is much appreciated: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eblana_db`.`person_details`, CONSTRAINT `person_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Email`) REFERENCES `ebook_details` (`Name of Ebook`))

Comment: Can you script the CREATE TABLE s
?

Comment: Created the tables first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference, please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: @Aaron I meant can you show **us** the CREATE TABLE s script?

Comment: @TSion.D.P I meant I manually created them, no script!

Comment: Ok cool, I seen on youtube as well, that you had to have corresponding rows e.g. ID in two tables.

Is that the case, if so I need to speak to the guy who gave me the information for the tables.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your table definition for your `person_details` table says that the column called `Email` is a foreign key to the column in your `ebook_details` column called `Ebook Name`.   So, when you go to load a `person_details` record saying something like

```
    Aaron Boyse     aboyse@example.com
```

MySQL looks for a row in your `ebook_details` table with an `Ebook Name` of `aboyse@example.com`. It doesn't find that row, so it throws an error.

That obviously makes no sense in your application domain.

You'll do well to study up on entities (rows) and relationships (foreign keys, etc).

Comment: Can I add an ID to correspond to the ID in the first table.

Comment: So, do I need to change the labels around?

Answer (score 0):

your Error says that  the email column is not set in the your csv- file (one or many line(s) )

The email (primary key in  ebook_details ) must not be null  incording to the message error.

Solution :
Write the file in a tmp-Table then update your table by selecting columns
like this

```
--In mysql
 update  your_table e
 select a,b, IFNULL(email,'Unknow') from tmp_table

--In sqlserver
 update your_table e
 select a,b, ISNULL(email,'Unknow') from tmp_table

--In oracle
 update your_table e
 select a,b, nvl(email,'Unknow') from tmp_table
```